# CSS drop shadow blurry on Mac Retina, clear and sharp on low-res Lenovo display

Tags: html, css, graphics

I'm using the following CSS to apply a drop-shadow to my navigation bar.

```
.navstyle {
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
    /* webkit filter syntax: x, y, blur radius */
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5));
    filter: url(shadow.svg#drop-shadow);
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Dropshadow(OffX=12, OffY=12,
    Color='#444')";
    filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Dropshadow(OffX=12, OffY=12, Color='#444')";
}
```

On my retina, Macbook Pro 2013 screen, the Nav text seem blurry as a result of the drop shadow (pic 1). On my attached lower resolution screen (lenovo) the text is sharper (pic 2). This seems counterintuitive to me, can anyone provide insight as to why the text looks bad on my retina screen?

**Macbook Pro Retina Display Screenshot**

[image: Imgur]

**Low-Res Lenovo Display**

[image: Imgur]

Comment: So if you remove the drop-shadow the text becomes sharp?

Comment: Correct, and I just verified.